# Texture painting from Plane to mesh? Like 3ds max

Tags: mesh, texturing, texture-painting

Hey there stack exchange, I wasn't able to find this question or answer so I thought I would ask it because I am so very stuck.

I have been using various methods to create realistic faces but I've found none as good as using a projection of an image in 3ds. the problem is i know blender not 3ds and my friend has to help me a lot in 3ds.

My question is this, in the picture below is there a way I can clone brush or projection paint or take the texture on that plane and "paint" it onto the mesh head behind it. they are perfectly aligned already but nothing I try works.

any help would be very appreciated.

[image]

Comment: use that texture as a stencil in texture paint mode, thats the only way you can...

Comment: Hello :). Perhaps projected UV map could be used here. What other methods have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried many methods, UV project is one of them.
I have seen other posts talking in very short details bout using the image texture node to bake the background image onto the mesh, but the person that answered the quest gave no instructions and was very rude to the other person.
There has to be a way i can turn the backround image to a stencil or bake it direction onto the mesh ?

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to turn the back round image into a stencil?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about texture painting, but this looks like a projected UV map.

1. Add the image texture to your model
2. Put the camera in front
3. Add the UV project Modifier and target the camera

[image]

Comment: That is an option I can try but it looks very inaccurate for lining up very fine details. I really just want to use the back round image to bake directly onto the mesh. lining up a camera would be very very hard.

Comment: Sure :) @Michael 's suggestion is probably better.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i just tried it out, it was, difficult to get things to line up, but thank you again.

Comment: I want to do what you did with that camera, just using the back round image instead. if that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'back round image' :). Perhaps add an image of your result into the original question.

Comment: Oh here it is. its basically the reference image you can add into blender.
I can't figure out how to add an image to my post here.
https://i.gyazo.com/efd12ce2408d0e9c59db4d65324c34c0.png

Comment: I get it now :). I'm not sure that's possible in Blender. But perhaps someone else will be able to help.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to turn a background or reference image or even a plane with a picture on it into a stencil?